# Lightgbm splits differently on the same dataset (one hot encoded vs one-vs-other split algorithm)

Tags: python, algorithm, lightgbm

When doing small tests on lightgbm, I found a case I could not understand.

I create a small dataset with categorical columns:

```
import pandas as pd

X = pd.DataFrame(
    [
        [0, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 0],
        [3, 3, 2],
        [2, 3, 2],
        [0, -3, 0],
        [0, 0, 1],
        [0, 3, 0],
        [1, 2.5, 1],
        [2, 5, 0],
        [3, -1.5, 2],
     ],
     columns=["col1", "col2", "col3"],
)
X["col1"] = X["col1"].astype("category")
X["col3"] = X["col3"].astype("category")
y = pd.Series([0, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 1])
```

and its associated one hot encoded version:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder

feats_to_encode = ["col1", "col3"]
enc = OneHotEncoder()
enc.fit(X[feats_to_encode])
X_one_hot_encoded = pd.DataFrame(
    enc.transform(X[feats_to_encode]).toarray(),
    columns=[
        feats_to_encode[feat_id] + str(cat)
        for feat_id in range(len(enc.categories_))
        for cat in enc.categories_[feat_id]
    ],
)
X_one_hot_encoded["col2"] = X["col2"]
```

I then trained 2 lightgbm models, with both the previous datasets. I know that lightgbm manages categorical columns with special algorithms. "When number of categories of one feature smaller than or equal to max_cat_to_onehot, one-vs-other split algorithm will be used" (see [max_cat_to_onehot](https://lightgbm.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Parameters.html#max_cat_to_onehot)). I would then naively expect that, since my categorical columns have less categories (4 and 3) than the parameter max_cat_to_onehot, I would get the same result with both the datasets, unless if the "one-vs-other split algorithm" is not equivalent to one hot encode categorical columns. I assumed this behaviour because of the names of the parameter, "max_cat_to_onehot", and the algorithm, "one-vs-other split algorithm".

```
from lightgbm import LGBMRegressor

params = {
    "n_estimators": 1,
    "max_depth": 2,
    "min_child_samples": 1,
    "importance_type": "gain",
    "max_cat_to_onehot": 10,
}

model = LGBMRegressor(**params)
model.fit(X, y)
print(model._Booster.dump_model()["tree_info"][0]["tree_structure"]["split_gain"]) # 0.30476200580596924

model = LGBMRegressor(**params)
model.fit(X_one_hot_encoded, y)
print(model._Booster.dump_model()["tree_info"][0]["tree_structure"]["split_gain"]) # 1.0666699409484863
```

The first split is different between the 2 models. The second model chose the best possible split, but this is not the case for the first one.

Does someone know the reason of this? I assume that my guess for the behaviour of "one-vs-other split algorithm" is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

I updated the lightgbm version, from 2.3.1 to 3.1.1. With the new version I got the expected results.